# LESS import reference does not add @media or invoke grid mixins

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

Recently I've discovered **reference** import option (http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options).

So I started refactoring my existing less files to remove duplications and take advantage of reference options. In one of my less file, I'm mixing Bootstrap 3 with my mixins:

```
@import (reference) "../../../../less/variables.less";
@import (reference) "../../../../less/vendor/bootstrap/variables.less";
@import (reference) "../../../../less/vendor/bootstrap/mixins.less";
@import (reference) "../../../../less/vendor/bootstrap/grid.less";

.horizontal-submit-container {
    .make-sm-column(6);
    .make-sm-column-offset(6);
}
```

After compilation with reference flag this is what I get from **horizontal-submit-container** mixin:

```
.horizontal-submit-container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

And this css is incomplete - it is missing some @media lines. However when I remove reference flag I get proper:

```
.horizontal-submit-container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .horizontal-submit-container {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .horizontal-submit-container {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be [a known bug of LESS in `reference` mode](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1469), that is nearing implementation to fix (as of 2-10-2014).

Comment: I am encountering this same issue as well! - This has been posted as well on https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1469

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until the [bug is fixed](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1469), you might try this (I have not actually tested this in reference mode):

```
.horizontal-submit-container {
    .make-sm-column; // copy the mixins themselves into it, then call them...
    .make-sm-column(6);
    .make-sm-column-offset(6);
}
```

It should actually make a local copy of the mixin with the `@media` in it, then when you call them, it is using that copy. Perhaps this will cause the queries to generate correctly.

Comment: @dragonfly: You accepted the answer, so did it work (since I could not test it at present)?

Comment: @dragonfly - I tried it out with Less v1.6.3 and it didn't work with this approach;